# Error on VSTS build summary page loading

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm getting flowing script error on loading of build summary page. This occurs when using "commonjs" compiler option. Please advice how to resolve this.

Uncaught Error: Module name "VSS/Controls" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

**Script section:**

```
<script src="scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    VSS.init( { 
        usePlatformScripts: true
    });

    VSS.ready(function() {
        require(["ext/status"], function () { });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: What's the detail code of you typescript? What's the result with this code? require(["ext/status","VSS/Controls"],function(){})

Comment: How do you load "VSS/Controls"?